# Password hash in apex oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i'm trying to hash or encrypt the password provided by the user in my apex oracle before store it in the DB table
How can i do it ? i tried using `DBMS_CRYPTO` but it always generate an error saying

```
identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared
```

Comment: You are missing execute privilege. It's not granted by default.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson how can i grant execute privileges ? i'm new to apex oracle

Comment: Someone with DBA privileges would `grant execute on dbms_crypto to yourusername`. I don't know Apex though, so possibly there are other tools built into the product. I would think you would want to encrypt (username + password + salt) as one string within the client itself, before comparing this to the equivalent encrypted string stored in the database.

Comment: OT: For some reason security guidelines for Oracle discourage granting this package for public. IMHO it does not make any sense.